# How to change UrlReferrer in WebClient

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I want to post data between the two WebApi services

Request.UrlReferrer in destination service always is null

Now I want to change the destination service UrlReferrer to the source service Url

```
using System.Net;

namespace Test
{
    public class CustomWebClient
    {
        private string SimplePost(string address, string request)
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                // How to change UrlReferer
                return client.UploadString(address, request);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That web client doesn't really run on the context of the client (Web API) that calls it and the referer will not be populated.

I can't test this right now but basically the `UrlReferer` is nothing more than the HTTP header `Referer`. So, in theory you can add that header to the `WebClient` yourself...

```
client.Headers.Add("Referer","whatever_you_want_to_add");
```

You'll be adding it manually which is not ideal, but it is the best you can do. Be aware that the `Referer` header is not set if:

- The resource referred to is a local file or uri
- The request is unsecured and the referred resource is secured